# How to make a try/except block that only skips a single line?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create multiple folders in my current directory so I'm using `os.mkdir()` to do that. The problem is that this function returns an error if the folder already exists so I created a `try`/`except` block.

I would like it to skip the line if it encounters an error. The problem is that this would require one block per directory as I want it to check every single one of them individually.

I do realize that there probably exists another function that doesn't return an error, but I just want to know if it's possible to tell the computer to keep reading the block and simply skip any line that gives it an error, but not any other line.

So if I want to create `dir1` to `dir5`, but `dir3` already exists, having something like:

```
try:
    os.mkdir('dir1')
    os.mkdir('dir2')
    os.mkdir('dir3')
    os.mkdir('dir4')
    os.mkdir('dir5')
except:
    pass
```

I would like it to still create directory 1 through 5 instead of only creating 1 and 2. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Sure, but not the way you specify.  You have to enter and leave the `try` block each time.  Perhaps this:

```
for f in ['dir1', 'dir2', 'dir3', 'dir4', 'dir5']:
    try:
        os.mkdir(f)
    except:
        pass
```

It's generally a bad idea to have a silent, global failure such as the above.  Instead, set your `except` block for a specific exception, and print a message to cover the event.

Comment: Just to add that specific error is `FileExistsError`

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the folder actually exists before trying `mkdir`

```
for folder in ['dir1', 'dir2', 'dir3', 'dir4', 'dir5']:
    if not os.path.isdir(folder):
        os.mkdir(folder)
```

Comment: this is subject to race condition, try/except is better/preferred way to do it.